# Get items selected from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]Hi I have a Windows Form application. I have a Textbox. I want to implement a functionality like when the user clicks on the textbox, a list should be made available to the user and then the item selected from the list should be filled in the textbox. The list should not be available if some other control is focussed other than the textbox. What would be the better way to do this? Should I implement the list in the same form as the textbox or should I use another form for the list?

---

> I want to implement a functionality like in the Tally Accounting
>   Software.

---

Comment: Sounds like a ComboBox to me...

Comment: Sounds like you need a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx)

Comment: No not a comboBox. I am aware of the comboBox, but I need a list somewhere away from the textbox, may be on the right side of the form, while the text Box is on the left. How can I get the listitem selected in FORM2 in a textbox in FORM1 where FORM1 is responsible to pop-in FORM2?

Comment: can you give a screenshot of this software because the software isn´t for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few events for the text box control you can use for this.

You could use Enter and Leave to control the .Visible or .Enabled property of your list.

Use one list and dynamically fill using the enter and leave. You will need a marker to indicate what textBox you are manipulating.

Example

```
    TextBox activeText;
    private void txtBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          lstMyList.dataSource = list1Data;
          activeText = (TextBox)sender;

    }

    private void lstMyList_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ListBox myList = (ListBox)sender; 
         activeText.Text = myList.SelectedValue.ToString();

    }
```

Maybe something like that?

Comment: That is what I have done for now, But the only trouble is that the list is there on the same form, and in that **place** of the form, I need to put other controls.

Comment: Then I would use a panel, as suggested by Paedow below. Just make the two control layouts and set them on top of each other. Then you can control it's visibility in the same way. Just use the panel and not the individual control.

And yes, you can set myList to invisible in design by changing its visible property.

Comment: If I put them on top of each other, only one of them is visible... How do I make one of them hidden while designing?

Comment: I don't think you do. You can make one hidden at runtime, but while you are building it the object will be visible. I misunderstood your question on that.

You can just lay them out, not on top of each other and put them in the same spot before you run it. All your controls will move with the container.

Comment: You are not getting the point. I have to show about 5 lists individually for each of 5 textboxes respectively. It would be pretty messy to hide 4 lists and then showing one and vice versa! also degining would be a headache.

Comment: Can you dynamically fill the list with the textBox selection then? I didn't know you had that many.

Comment: Ya, that seems ok, but not the perfect solution. I will be displaying the selected list item in the textbox which led to that particular list. I will try this and then post back.

Comment: Perfect! Will try this in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Make a [panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) which contains a [listView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx)

When you use a panel you can change the [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) property to hide all the content in it.

```
panel1.Visible = true; //visible
panel1.Visible = false; //invisible
```

Now you can say: when the [textbox is clicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.click%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) show me the list:

```
private void textbox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = true;
}
```

Now, when the form gains focus, you can hide the list:

```
private void form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

When the selected [item of the List changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged.aspx) set the Text of your Textbox:

```
private void ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(Object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach ( ListViewItem item in ListView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        textbox1.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you truly mean by **layer**?

Comment: Is there a way to make it invisible in the Form Design View also? Its because I need to put some other controls in the place which list is already occupying..

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal Don´t know if it works I´m sitting at an iMac here, so I didn´t test it...

Answer (score 0):

In my view use a separate form and in new form all list will be displayed. Clicking on textbox you need to show the new form.

For Getting the selected items there are many ways

1. Send a LIST parameter to New form(Constructor)
2. Get method of new form when form is closed
3. Static global variable

METHOD 1.

```
FORM2 frm = new FORM2(LIST<string> items)
frm.ShowDailog();
textBox1.text = add items from  items
```

METHOD 2.

```
FORM2 frm = new FORM2()
if(frm.ShowDailog() == DialogResults.Ok)
{
 textBox1.text = frm.GetSelectedItems();
}
```

Comment: Briefly, Can you please tell me how can I retrieve values selected from another form to a form that is already open.

Its like: FORM1--> FORM2
FORM2--> FORM1 and all this time FORM1 is open! form2 is just a dialog!

Comment: Please use FORM1 and FORM2... I am not getting it.

Comment: Form1 is initially open. I open Form2 and Form2 has to send parameters (list items) back to Form1. Now, How will Form1 recieve those parameters as it is already open!

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal, In textbox how you want to display? I mean each item with Comma separation?

Comment: Please check the screenshot. The textbox selection opened the list and then the item **selected** from the list is finally displayed in the textbox. And then this goes on for other textboxes.